# Installing Python ez_setup.py

Tags: python, easy-install

So I'm trying to download ez_setup.py according to the instructions for Mac here:

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools#unix-based-systems-including-mac-os-x

Am I just supposed to run:

```
wget https://bitbucket.org/pypa/setuptools/raw/bootstrap/ez_setup.py -O - | python
```

If so, I get a syntax error (carrot points to the s in "https").  Any ideas what's going on here?

Thanks for the help,
Mariogs

Comment: Depending on your needs, you may (also) like [`pip`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip). I can't really tell what to use best (I prefer `pip`), but you can use them next to each other. Just in case, `pip` can be installed using the one-liner `curl https://raw.github.com/pypa/pip/master/contrib/get-pip.py | python`, possibly preceeded by `sudo`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you're running this command from within the Python shell.
Run it instead from the command line shell (Terminal), and you should be good to go.

**Update**

Unfortunately, `wget` is not installed by default on OS X. You can install for example using homebrew: `brew install wget`, but that would require you to first install homebrew (which may have conveniences for other software later though).

Instead, you can use `curl` as a replacement for `wget`:

```
curl https://bitbucket.org/pypa/setuptools/raw/bootstrap/ez_setup.py | python
```

Note that `curl` automatically sends its output to `stdout`, which means that you don't those `-O -` options.

NB: you may need to prepend `sudo` to that line:

```
curl https://bitbucket.org/pypa/setuptools/raw/bootstrap/ez_setup.py | sudo python
```

Comment: so when I run it from the command line (in iTerm and in Terminal), I get: -bash: wget: command not found                                     Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: @Mariogs Ah, sorry, I had forgotten `wget` is not installed on OS X by default. See my updated answer.

Comment: no worries, appreciate the help.  So now I get: Warning: It appears you have MacPorts or Fink installed.
Software installed with other package managers causes known problems for
Homebrew. If a formula fails to build, uninstall MacPorts/Fink and try again.
Warning: wget-1.14 already installed, it's just not linked              I've tried uninstalling fink but have run into other errors...

Comment: Also, when I try to curl (while prepending "sudo") I get:               The following error occurred while trying to add or remove files in the
installation directory:

    [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/test-easy-install-25760.pth'

The installation directory you specified (via --install-dir, --prefix, or
the distutils default setting) was:

    /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/

Comment: Ok, so you do have `wget` already. It's probably in `/opt/local/bin` or `/sw/bin`, but you never set your `PATH` to those directories, so it didn't get picked up. But let's stick with `curl` for now, since that's on the system by default: I've updated my answer to move the `sudo` into the right place (in front of `python`, which is the command that requires root access, not `curl`).